# Configure WebStorm to delete *.ts *.js *.js.map all together

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Currently after deleting a TypeScript (`*.ts`) file in WebStorm 2016 the compiled `*.js` and `*.js.map` from the deleted `*.ts` file remain and should be again manually deleted.

Is there a way to delete this 3 files all together since both `*.js` and `*.js.map` are dependent on the `*.ts` file?

Example:

Create `MyClass.ts` (automatically), `MyClass.js` and `MyClass.js.map` will be created. When you delete `MyClass.ts` the other 2 files (`MyClass.js`, `MyClass.js.map`) will not be deleted!

Comment: output the generated files (.js and .js.map) to a different folder using the `outDir` option in `tsconfig.json`. The build folder can then easily be cleaned